# How do we change the way print displays a table

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable, meta-method

Assuming I have a piece of code such as the following

```
aTable = {aValue=1}
aTable_mt = {}
print(aTable)
```

What must I do to make Lua print something like `aTable current aValue = 1` as opposed to `table: 0x01ab1d2`.

So far I've tried setting the `__tostring` metamethod but that doesn't seem to be invoked by `print`. Is there some metamethod I've been missing or does the answer have nothing to do with metamethods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__tostring` works:

```
aTable = {aValue=1}
local mt = {__tostring = function(t) 
                           local result = ''
                           for k, v in pairs(t) do
                             result = result .. tostring(k) .. ' ' .. tostring(v) .. ''
                           end
                           return result
                         end}      

setmetatable(aTable, mt)    

print(aTable)
```

This prints `aValue 1` (with one extra whitespace, remove it in real code). The `aTable` part is not available, because `aTable` is a variable that references the table, not the content of the table itself.

Comment: Ah my bad, i forgot to return a value! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you set the metamethod, but the following code prints "stringified" for me:

```
local aTable = {a = 1, b = 2}
setmetatable(aTable, {__tostring = function() return "stringified" end})
print(aTable)
```

Comment: Ah my bad, i forgot to return a value! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want lua to generally print all tables human readable, you could
hook up/overwrite the print function:

```
local orig_print = print

print = function(...)
  local args = {...}
  for i,arg in ipairs(args) do
    if type(arg) == 'table' then
      args[i] = serialize(arg)
    end
  end
  orig_print(table.unpack(args))
end
```

`serialize` could be [serpent](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/programming/serpent-lua-serializer-pretty-printer) or some other lib from [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization)

Note that this must be done before any other module/script is loaded.