# What metamethod is print()?

Tags: lua

I am making a custom lua enviroment in c++ using metamethods. I am confused of what metamethod would call print()? I think it is __call but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we change the way print displays a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639479/how-do-we-change-the-way-print-displays-a-table)

Comment: you may call print from any metamethod. please explain what you want to achieve as your question doesn't make too much sense as is.

Answer (score 3):

No metamethod calls `print`.

On the other hand, `print` calls `tostring`, which respects the `__tostring` metamethod.